# Strategy to define domain data used in Integration Tests

Tags: domain-model, integration-tests

In my job we work in a data driven web application and performance is a important business feature. So, queries in the model tier are frequently large
and contain much of the business logic. As a result we have many Integrations Tests that rely in XML datasets used by our test framework(an abstraction to DbUnit) to populate data model. We have migration scripts containing DDL and data domain changes that are executed before all tests, but the framework clean all tables before the execution of each test. We are considering changing this behavior and do not clean domain tables anymore. 
We would continue defining application data specific to the tests in each XML dataset, but regarding the domain data:

**Should we continue defining it in each XML dataset too?**

Pros:

- Tests will not break in case of domain data changes that do not
  impact business logic.
- We can define a small subset of domain data
  sufficient to test business logic.

Cons:

- It may be necessary create too many tables and rows to represent all relationships that the test need.
- It would be expensive to fix datasets in case of changes in the data model.
- Data duplication in many XML datasets in the project.

**Should we do not clean the domain data inserted by the scripts? These scripts would execute
only one time before all Integration Tests and the data would be common to all tests.**

Pros:

- Tests will break in case of domain data changes that impact business logic.
- It would be easier to create data to the test, because we only need to create application data.

Cons:

- Tests may break in case of domain data changes that do not impact business logic. We should be careful to not test things like number
  of rows returned or text attributes of domain entities.
- If to test some business logic we need specific characteristics of the domain data that we cannot assume it is true in production, we
  need to change  the actual data domain before the execution of the
  test and rollback in the end. But how change something that is
  mutable and unpredictable?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is a mix:

- 1st step: Run integration test in a clean database, populated and discarded on each execution. This way you test your code with the lasts version of your database model.
- 2nd step, when you want to pick a release candidate from the step 1, because you want to promote it (and you don't usually promote every candidate), then you run the full integration tests in a production like database. You test your migration scripts and the integration of your code to the production environment.